# APK architecture for Facebook developer preview

Tags: android, facebook, apk, armv7, android-x86

Our application depends on vlc library which is prepared for different CPU architectures - x86 and arm-v7 for now. We need to submit application to Facebook review (for permissions approve). First time I've prepared a build with arm architecture, but received answer that reviewer experienced some difficulties with the build. Maybe somebody know - android apps are reviewed on emulator or on real devices? Which architecture should be provided for the review?

Comment: I think you have to provide all builds i.e one for every architecture

Comment: @VivekMishra - builds uploading performed by customer, not directly by me. As far as I know - there is possibility to upload only one file